# Rolling forecast for data detrended by model fitting

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima

Suppose I have an actual time-series $a$ on which I fit a linear regression model with trendline $t$.

[image]

I then subtract $t$ from $a$ to detrend the series by model fitting. This gives me the detrended series $d$. On this series, I want to train SARIMA models with a rolling forecast $f$

[image]

Now, the first forecast can easily be calculated by SARIMA and then inversed to get the forecast for the actual series. $f(a_i) = f(d_i) + t_i$. To calculate the subsequent forecasts, I have two ways to move forward and I am confused as to which would be the better choice.

1. Calculate subsequent forecasts based on the same trendline, by predicting the future step $t_i$ for trendline, subtracting it from $a_i$, which would give $d_i$ and using SARIMA to find $f_i$, then inversing it. (Pretty much like finding the first forecast)
2. Fit a new linear regression model on the now longer series ((length of $a$) + $i$) and use the new trendline to subtract from $a$, and do the remaining as before. This would mean I will train a new LR model at every step to detrend and then inverse, and this would change the entire series ($d$) at each step.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/master/df_timeseries.csv')
train_df, test_df, val_df, val2_df = df[:-90], df[-30:], df[-90:-60], df[-60:-30]
```

The figures are all created on `train_df`

Comment: You could just not de-trend before you hand it over to SARIMA and that will simplify your whole pipeline.

Comment: I am already doing that too. I wanted to try more variations to see which would yield me better results, hence this.